# How do I get hibernate to generate Oracle's FOR UPDATE WAIT 10 syntax

Tags: oracle, hibernate, locking, wait

I have a line of code like this:

```
final Foo foo = (Foo)session.get( Foo.class, id, LockMode.UPGRADE );
```

This generates a `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`.

However, I'm only willing to wait for 10 seconds to obtain the lock and there for I would like a `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE WAIT 10`.  How can I get hibernate to generate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to use the [`LockOptions`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/LockOptions.html) class with `SetTimeout()` rather than LockMode.

For this, we upgraded to Hibernate 3.6 only to find it is broken for Oracle.

Comment: I assume you are referring to this bug that indicates LockMode/LockOptions are broken for Oracle: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5275. Note that this bug is fixed and backported to Hibernate 3.6.10

Comment: @ChrisDail: Yes, I believe that was the bug that caused us issues.  We created our own Oracle dialect (as described in the bug you linked).  Glad to hear that it's fixed so we can remove our dialect next release.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't.

But you could just wait and set the [transaction timeout](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation-timeout). It depends on what you want to do when you don't get the lock. When you roll back the whole thing anyway, it doesn't matter much.

Another way is to lock without wait, and try to lock it a second later, up to ten times. This isn't nice but some kind of solution anyway.

Comment: I can't see the transaction timeout helping much.  If a lock is held on the Oracle side, the SQL statement is going to wait forever before returning and giving Hibernate a chance to timeout.

Comment: Isn't the transaction timeout on the DBMS side? If it wasn't it isn't of much use indeed.